# Time Over, Time Elapsed and Time Countdown on javascript to load in body in php

Tags: javascript, php, counter, countdown, countdowntimer

Please Help!

I want to load Time Over, Time Elapsed dan Time Countdown on web page when student do the exam, I always failed to show it when the web page (exam page) load.

are my script right?

```
<?php $waktu=60;?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var TimeOver = true;

     function getJam(Tanggal)
     {
       Jam =  (Tanggal.getHours() < 10) ? "0"  + Tanggal.getHours()  + ":" : Tanggal.getHours() + ":";
       Jam += (Tanggal.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + Tanggal.getMinutes() + ":" : Tanggal.getMinutes() + ":";
       Jam += (Tanggal.getSeconds() < 10) ? "0" + Tanggal.getSeconds() : Tanggal.getSeconds();
       return Jam;
     }

     function dispJam()
     {
        TglCur = new Date();
        var a = document.getElementById("Watch");
        a.value = getJam(TglCur);
        var b = document.getElementById("TimeTaken");
        b.value = getWaktu(TglCur,TglStart);
        var c = document.getElementById("TimeLeft");
        if ((Tgl.getTime() - TglCur.getTime()) <= 0)
        {
         if(TimeOver) TimeOverWarn();
         c.value = "Habis";
        }
        else
        {
         c.value = getWaktu(Tgl,TglCur);
         setTimeout("dispJam()",1000);
        }
     }

     function getWaktu(Tgl,TglCur)
     {
        TmLf = Tgl.getTime() - TglCur.getTime();
        TmLfHours = Math.floor(TmLf/3600000) ;
        TmLfMinutes = Math.floor((TmLf%3600000)/60000);
        TmLfSeconds = Math.round((TmLf%60000)/1000);
        TmLfStr = (TmLfHours < 10) ? "0" + TmLfHours + ":" : TmLfHours + ":";
        TmLfStr += (TmLfMinutes < 10) ? "0" + TmLfMinutes + ":" : TmLfMinutes + ":";
        TmLfStr += (TmLfSeconds < 10) ? "0" + TmLfSeconds : TmLfSeconds;
        return TmLfStr;
     }

     function TimeOverWarn()
     {
        alert("\n Maaf " + <?php echo $nama?> + " ....\n Waktu Anda Habis");
        TimeOver = true;
        return true;
     }

     Tanggal =  new Date();
     Tgl = new Date();
     TglStart = new Date();
     ArrayBulan = new Array("Januari","Pebruari","Maret","April","Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","Nopember","Desember");
     Tahun =  Tanggal.getYear();
     TglStr = Tanggal.getDate()  + " " + ArrayBulan[Tanggal.getMonth()] + " " + Tahun;
     Tgl.setTime(Tgl.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    </script>

    <script language="javascript"> 
    function selesai() {
    document.ljkform.submit.click();
    clearTimeout(timeID);
    } 
    function timer() {
    timeID=setTimeout("selesai()",60000 * <?php echo $waktu;?>);
    }
    </script>
```

I use these script in body load.

Here is my script to load it.

```
    <body onLoad="dispJam();timer();">
        <table>
            <FORM NAME="User"> 
                <tr><td><center>Sisa Waktu<br><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="TimeLeft" id="TimeLeft" SIZE="8"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><center>Waktu<br><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="TimeTaken" id="TimeTaken" SIZE="8"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><center>Sekarang Jam<br><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Watch" id="Watch" SIZE="8"></td></tr>
            </FORM>
        </table>
        <form name="ljkform" method="post" action="hasil_tes.php?idtest=<?php echo $idtest;?>&idanggota=<?php echo $idanggota;?>">
<!-- script to show the question form -->
        </form>
    </body>
```

Many thanks before...

Comment: Your code works... There is no function called - timer(); . So remove that from body onload.  Change your message in function TimeOverWarn() to - alert("\n Maaf  " + <?php echo $nama ?> + " ....\n Waktu Anda Habis");

Comment: thank you, I'll try it..

Comment: it still won't show the time... I forgot some script.. I update my script, please check it again... many thanks to you..

Comment: Make sure that all the php variables you are using, are defined. If any one of them is not available, then it will not work. Also learn to use console in chrome. So that you are aware of such little errors. Otherwise the code works.